# Directive scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I am using a directive for three consecutive time in html page, the scope variable i am passing to different at every time but it is taking all the scope variable from the third directive ?, for example
first time,

```
<my-dir is-active=true></my-dir>
```

sec time,

```
<my-dir is-active="true"></my-dir>
```

third time,

```
<my-dir is-Active="true" is-action="true"><my-dir>
```

JS:

```
angular
.module('app')
.directive("myDir", function(){
 scope:{
  isActive:'@',
  isAction:'@'
 },
controller:[function('$scope'){
  $scope.isAction ? doAction() : doActive();

 function doAction()
 {
    console.log('in action');
  }

  function doActive()
  {
    console.log('in active');
  }
}]
})
```

here at every time I am getting "In action" log three time ? it should be only one time as I am not passing the "IsAction" scope from the directive for the first two time ?

Comment: You have quite a few syntax errors in this code...

Comment: @hsingh additionally you will need to add `restrict: 'E'` in your directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure your issues were just syntax errors.  If you correct those it seems to work correctly.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ALW6sxyLGhocBwofgvTB?p=preview)

```
.directive("myDir", function(){
  return {
   scope:{
    isActive:'@',
    isAction:'@'
   },
   controller:function($scope){
      $scope.isAction ? doAction() : doActive();

      function doAction()
      {
        console.log('in action');
      }

      function doActive()
      {
        console.log('in active');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: yea, i have corrected it and still same issue is persist and we are using the restrict: 'E' in our code ?

Comment: Did you look at the plunker?  I dont see the problem there.

Comment: Thanks, that was my fault it is working as expecting :)